# Unable to retrieve GET parameters from Jquery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am serializing values from inputs within a div and sending them to a controller.
I can see the string sent and it is like that:

> jsonData=nome%3DGuilherme%2BLongo%26possuiPortariaPropria%3Don

This is how I am sending:

```
var jsonArr = $('.condHorizontalIlhasBasico :input').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Session/setJsonValue',
                type: "POST",
                data: { "jsonData": jsonArr },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    ...
                },
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                    ...
                },
                error: function () {
                    ...
                }
            });
```

Now I am trying to get it like that:

```
public string setJsonValue()
{
   string data = Request.QueryString["jsonData"];
   return data;
   //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[param] = value;            
}
```

But all I get is an empty string.
Can´t figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a post parameter - not a query string parameter. Try the following

```
public string setJsonValue()
{
   string data = Request.Params["jsonData"];
   return data;
   //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[param] = value;            
}
```